# Pressure and velocity dispersion

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, ideal-gas, galaxies, galaxy-clusters

I’m reading [this paper](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwil-eHt4L2AAxXw4TgGHZEoAZkQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2Fastro-ph%2F0212293&usg=AOvVaw1HXriZ71UUbcfvRa3UIP4H&opi=89978449)
whose Eq(2) I’m a little concerned about. Sanders has tried to relate the pressure with the velocity dispersion of particles using the relation $P=
\rho\sigma^2$ where $\sigma$  is the 1-D velocity dispersion. The equation would make sense to me if it was the velocity itself where it could be a direct consequence of ideal gas law:
$$P=nmv^2 \implies P=\rho V^2$$ , n being the number density and m being the mass of the particle- all of this being analogous to elementary thermodynamics. But I am not sure why this should hold with $\sigma$ in place of v. Please explain.